# Toggle div based on multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, toggle

The following code is what I am working with:

```
<select id="tables" multiple="multiple" name="tables[]">
      <option>users</option>
      <option>options</option>
      <option>posts</option>
</select>

<div id="something" style="hidden">Stuff goes here.</div>
```

What I am trying to do is have a div toggle when a specific option is selected in the dropdown. For instance, if only the 'options' option is selected, the div shows. Deselected, it gets removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/uA7XD/

JS:

```
window.changeHandler = function() {
    var op = $("#tables option[value='options']:selected");
    if (op.length)
        $("#something").show();
    else
        $("#something").hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="tables" multiple="multiple" name="tables[]" onchange="changeHandler()">
      <option>users</option>
      <option>options</option>
      <option>posts</option>
</select>

<div id="something" class="hidden">Stuff goes here.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `if (op.length)` and the dual calls to `.show()` and `.hide()`, you could just use: `$("#something").toggle(op.length > 0)` or all in a single line: `$("#something").toggle($("#tables option[value='options']:selected").length > 0));`

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that is perfectly valid, but he might want to use a different effect or carry out a number of operations.

Comment: Yeah I cleaned that up as soon as I saw the code - thanks tho @jfriend00.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tables').change(function(e){
  $('#something').toggle($(this).val() == 'options');
});
```

On a selection change, show/hide the div if the selected option's value is equal to "options"

**Update** for multi-select:

```
$('#tables').change(function(e){
    $('#something').toggle($('option[value="options"]:selected',this).length > 0);
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NXHnp/1/

Comment: Thanks Brad - I had implemented something similar with the change event but didn't seem to be working properly. There is one issue with your code however. If more than one option is selected (say, both users and options), the div won't toggle.

Comment: @mousesports It will with mine *nudge nudge wink wink*

Comment: @mousesports: See my update, which will work for multiple options

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#tables').live('click', function(){
    if($('#tables').val() == 'options')
      $('#something').slideDown();
    else
      $('#something').slideUp();
  });
```